# How to disable all notifications in chromium kiosk mode, on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian

I have currently running an autostart file after booting up my Raspberry Pi 3. In this file i want to run Chromium in kioskmode and disable all notifications. I tried some solutions that i found on the internet, but i can't get rid of the Restore pages? notification after a hard shutdown. What do i need to add to my autostart file?

(I can't run the browser in incognito-mode because i want to use caching)

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi

@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank

@chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-restore-session-state --disable-features=TranslateUI --disable-session-crashed-bubble www.google.com
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just add --app= to the target url:

```
@chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-restore-session-state --disable-features=TranslateUI --disable-session-crashed-bubble --app=www.google.com
```

And this way you get rid of this annoying message of restoring pages.

I hope it helps to you, because for me it works perfectly,
David Lyons

Comment: I have done this with the `--app url` but still receive the message popup that chromium could not auto update and needs to be re-installed.

Comment: FYI, this is a bug in Raspbian Chromium, see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=264399

Comment: You can avoid the update message by delaying the update check by a long time:
 --check-for-update-interval=2592000

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I use on kiosk machines (including raspberry pi 3). The idea is to vanish flags chromium relies on when showing a popup. Flags are located within profile's "Preferences" which is a json formatted file. You are interested in two values:

```
"exit_type":"Crashed",
"exited_cleanly":false,
```

They should be replaced by

```
"exit_type":"None",
"exited_cleanly":true,
```

Personally I use sed to make the replacement:

```
# remove crashed notification
PROFILE_PREF="$HOME/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences"
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":\s*false/"exited_cleanly":true/' "$PROFILE_PREF"
sed -i 's/"exit_type":\s*"Crashed"/"exit_type":"None"/' "$PROFILE_PREF"
```

but you may want to use e.g. `jq` to make the script more clear, or use smth else you prefer. Note, a replacement should be made **before** you start Chrome/Chromium.

P.S. The path I set to PROFILE_PREF is correct for default profile of Chromium in Linux. The exact place of your profile depends on your OS and browser.

Update:
Finally, I found a source I got a solution from: 
https://superuser.com/questions/461035/disable-google-chrome-session-restore-functionality

Answer (score 0):

As of now these parameters are working fine for me:

```
chromium-browser --disable --disable-translate --disable-infobars --disable-suggestions-service --disable-save-password-bubble --start-maximized  --noerrdialogs --disable-component-update --kiosk --incognito https://stackoverflow.com/
```